# Cancel 'on' event in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have the following jQuery script in my code, that executes at the end of a CSS animation:

```
$('.player').on('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
    gameOver();
});
```

I'd like to know how can I cancel or unset this, so that the `gameOver` function will not be executed anymore at the end of the animation.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/off/. Reading the documentation before asking here is always a good idea.

Comment: `$('.player').on("webkitAnimationEnd.gameOver")` with `$('.player').off("webkitAnimationEnd.gameOver")` should do it?

Comment: *"To remove events bound with `.on()`, see `.off()`. To attach an event that runs only once and then removes itself, see `.one()`"* - First paragraph of [`.on()` doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @ChrisSpittles: Wouldn't that `off` all the handlers on that event?

Comment: Use one() http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: @abhitalks it would only remove all instances of the webkitAnimationEnd event bound to the elements passed through the selector, but you can always name space it so only that instance is removed.

Comment: @ChrisSpittles: Yes. Namespacing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't show any effort to solve the problem

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I didn't know about the off() handler  (or the one(), which is even better) and my search on 'how to cancel on events' didn't get me any good results, so I asked here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Option 1: .one()

This will run once and never again until this code is bound again.

```
$('.player').one('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
    gameOver();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/one/

---

## Option 2: .off()

Use off like this:

```
$('.player').on('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
     gameOver();
});

function gameOver() {        
     $('.player').off('webkitAnimationEnd');
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/off/

---

## Option 3

If you have multiple animation events bound to the same element, use namespacing to differentiate:

```
$('.player').on('webkitAnimationEnd.gameOver', function() {
        gameOver();
});

function gameOver() {        
     $('.player').off('webkitAnimationEnd.gameOver');
}
```

Comment: Polluting the `gameOver` domain logic with DOM logic is not quite appealing. Just call `off` after calling `gameOver`.